# Music library management (iTunes & Spotify hybrid)

Tags: music, networking

First of all: I am on Mac OS X and would love to stay here, but I can switch to Linux if needed (Virtual Machines).

I am looking for an iTunes and Spotify mixture.

I have a great music collection that I like to share and create playlists with. I discover music on Spotify and love the integration in Clementine 1.2. I like iTunes GUI and the ability to share the music around the house. So I don't have to copy the music to every PC.

So the software should be able to have a "share" function.
What I also love about Spotify is the remote-editing on playlists.

My current setup allows me to SSH into my server at home and play music from around the world. But I can only play the music, not edit it (stars rating, add infos, correct a mistake …).

Even at home I can't do that with iTunes. I have to create a VNC connection to the server to actually edit something.

Also adding music is a pain because of these reasons.

Clementine is pretty near to what I need, it also integrates Spotify, but it can't share the music on the network (as far as I know).

So I'm looking for a software that is similar to Clementine, but can also remote-edit and share its contents.

I am prepared to pay for it, if there is a solution. And I would love to find a solution that is made Open Source and extendable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Subsonic](http://www.subsonic.org/pages/index.jsp) seems to meet your requirements. It's a music manager that is used on server and allows you to :

- **Stream music**, and **share** it (but you won't need to copy anything)
- **Edit tag**, **stars rating**, add infos, on a user basis
- Is integrated to Clementine too (but I recon I prefer to use the playlist instead of the Subsonic plugin).
- It is **open-source**, wrote in Java
- Works on **Windows**, **Linux**, and **Mac OS X** !
- It has a lot of **others apps compatible** (Android, iOs, PC) through a remote API. But for that functionality you need to pay **a monthly fee** (of only 1$ per month, which is quite honest for the amount of features provided).
- Except for the remote API (which i described just above), Subsonic is **free** !

Just a personal piece of mind : If you have a server, and don't use services like Spotify, Google Music or Deezer, then Subsonic is a must have.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am using Madsonic now, which is a great fork of Subsonic.

Comment: Update: Many month later I can still recommend Subsonic/Madsonic, but would also point to Plex (which has better support for mobile usage) and JamStash (My GoTo Web-Player besides Plex when using Subsonic).